# How to exclude packing native libs but still compile out to stripped&merged_native_libs dir in android gradle

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, ndk-build

I'm try to using

```
    packingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/*/*'
    }
```

Then the libs ware excluded in apk file.I also want to get those stripped native libs, but the only I can find are in `build/intermediates/cmake/release/obj/{abi-name}/xxx .so` which are not be stripped.

So, is there anyway to **exclude packing libs in apk** but still compiled out to  dir `stripped_native_libs` or `merged_native_libs` which are **stripped**?